# Mouseover and Mouseout javascript not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, video, mouseover, mouseout

I've written some basic Javascript code to work with the videos on my website. Basically I have embedded video content, placed a transparent and clickable div over the video that when hovered over will play the video behind it, then pause when the mouse is moved away. It works flawlessly on Chrome and Safari (not tested IE, I work on a Mac) but not at all on Firefox, the videos do not play. I've searched here and other places for a reason why, but haven't been able to find anything. I've only started playing with Javascript the last couple of weeks so I wouldn't be surprised if I've missed something obvious!

```
<div class="sectionWrapper">
<a href="http://weathereddown.co.uk">
<div id="sales-section" class="video-block" onmouseover="playVideo1()" onmouseout="playVideo1()"></div>
</a>

<div class="videoWrapper">
<div id="wistia_92lscndvjx" class="wistia_embed" style="width:900px;height:506px;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>

<script charset="ISO-8859-1" src="//fast.wistia.com/assets/external/E-v1.js"></script>
<script>
wistiaEmbed = Wistia.embed("92lscndvjx", {
  videoFoam: true
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var open = false;
    function playVideo1() {
        open = !open
        if (open == true) {
                document.getElementById('wistia_8').play();
        }
        else {
                document.getElementById('wistia_8').pause();
        }
    }
</script>
</div>
```

The Id references ('wistia_8') are correct, they refer to the code automatically generated on the page by the Wistia embed code.

Comment: Do the event(s) trigger? Any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the same methods as the W3Schools site but instead of hooking up the buttons use your mouseover mouseout events instead!

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_js_prop)

Hope this helps!